# Event Source Live streaming in Ruby on rails onError method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, server-sent-events

I'm trying to implement basic Rails 4 code with Event Wource API & Action controller live. Everything is fine but I'm not able to reach event listener.

Controller code:

```
  class HomeController < ApplicationController
            include ActionController::Live
     def tester 
            response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/event-stream"
            3.times do |n|
            response.stream.write "message: hellow world! \n\n"
            sleep 2
    end
end
```

Js code:

```
var evSource = new EventSource("/home/tester");

evSource.onopen = function (e) {
  console.log("OPEN state \n"+e.data);
};

evSource.addEventListener('message',function(e){
console.log("EventListener .. code..");
},false);

evSource.onerror = function (e) {
   console.log("Error State  \n\n"+e.data);
};
```

When I reload the page, my console output was **"OPEN state" & then "Error State"**. Event listener code was not displaying.

1. When I'm curling the page, **"message: Hellow world!"** was displaying.
2. I changed in development.rb

   `config.cache_classes = true`
   `config.eager_load = true`
3. My browsers are chrome & firefox are latest versions, so no issues with them

Where I'm missing? suggestions please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event format for server-sent events is

```
"data: message text\n\n"
```

So, in your case it should be like:

```
response.stream.write "data: hello world! \n\n"
```

Check [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) for reference.

Comment: Yeah, That's correct.. Where i missed is instead of "data:" , i used "message:"  i mean what client sending is not what server looking for